# Parse a string before the Last Index Of a character in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I started with this but is it the best way to perform the task?

```
select  
    reverse(
        substring(reverse(some_field),
        charindex('-', reverse(some_field)) + 1, 
        len(some_field) - charindex('-', reverse(some_field)))) 
from SomeTable
```

1. How does SQL Server treat the
   multiple calls to
   `reverse(some_field)`?
2. Besides a UDF and iterating through
   the string looking for `charindex`
   of the '-' and storing the last
   index of it, is there a more
   efficient way to perform this task in T-SQL?

Note that what I have works, I just am really wondering if it is the best way about it.

Below are some sample values for some_field.

```
s2-st, s1-st, s3-st, s3-sss-zzz, s4-sss-zzzz
```

EDIT:

Sample output for this would be...

```
s1, s2, s3-sss, s3, s4-sss
```

The solution ErikE wrote is actually getting the end of the string so everything after the last hyphen.  I just modified his version to get everything before it instead using a similar method with the `left` function.  Thanks for all of your your help.

```
select left(some_field, abs(charindex('-', reverse(some_field)) - len(some_field)))
    from (select 's2-st' as some_field
        union select 's1-st'
        union select 's3-st'
        union select 's3-sss-zzz'
        union select 's4-sss-zzzz') as SomeTable
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May I suggest this simplification of your expression:

```
select right(some_field, charindex('-', reverse(some_field)) - 1)
from SomeTable
```

Also, there's no harm, as far as I know, in specifying 8000 characters in length with the substring function when you want the rest of the string. As long as it's not varchar(max), it works just fine.

If this is something you have to do all the time, over and over, how about #1 splitting out the data into separate columns and storing it that way, or #2 adding a calculated column with an index on it, which will perform the calculation once at update/insert time and not again later.

Last, I don't know if SQL Server is smart enough to reverse(some_field) only once and inject it into the other instance. When I get some time I'll try to figure it out.

**Update**

Oops, somehow I got backwards what you wanted. Sorry about that. The new expression you showed can still be simplified a little:

```
select left(some_field, len(some_field) - charindex('-', reverse(some_field)))
from (
   select 's2-st'
   union all select 's1-st'
   union all select 's3-st'
   union all select 's3-sss-zzz'
   union all select 's4-sss-zzzz'
   union all select 's5'
) X (some_field)
```

The abs() in your expression was just reversing the sign. So I put `+ len - charindex` instead of `+ charindex - len` and all is well now. It even works for strings without dashes.

One more thing to mention: your `UNION SELECT`s should be `UNION ALL SELECT` because without the `ALL`, the engine has to remove duplicates just as if you'd indicated `SELECT DISTINCT`. Simply get in the habit of using `ALL` and you'll be much better off. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about #1, but I would say that you might be better off doing this in code.  Is there a reason you have to do it in the database?

Are you experiencing performance problems because of some similar code or is this purely hypothetical.

Comment: It's being done in SQL because that's really the only option due to a hack and someone being lazy (not me). I was asked if there was a way I could get the values for them so I provided it to them and cautioned them of it's use. I have always wondered about using functions like replace or reverse in selects when they are on the same fields and how that works. I figured this was a good example problem that I encountered to ask the question from. I agree that the preferrable method would be to do it in client code somehow.

Comment: BTW - forgot to mention I am not experiencing performance problems, but often I am writing queries that operate on thousands of rows and use string functions for populating reporting tables and curious how things work.  As you know, anything I can do to optimize query performance is always a plus.

Answer (score 0):

I am also not sure how SQL Server handles the multiple calls to REVERSE and CHARINDEX.

You can eliminate the last call to CHARINDEX since you want to take everything to the end of the string:

```
select  
    reverse(
        substring(reverse(some_field),
        charindex('-', reverse(some_field)) + 1, 
        len(some_field))) 
from SomeTable
```

Although I would recommend against it, you could also replace the LEN function call with the size of the column:

```
select  
    reverse(
        substring(reverse(some_field),
        charindex('-', reverse(some_field)) + 1, 
        1024)) 
from SomeTable
```

I am curious how much of a difference either of these changes would make.

Answer (score 0):

1. The 3 inner reverses are discrete from each other. The outer reverse will reverse anything that is already reversed by the inner ones.
2. ErikE's approach is best as a pure TSQL solution. You don't need LEN